# How to fix this code so that it wont delete the sheets mentioned?

Tags: excel, vba

**This code is not working. I want to keep the sheets I have mentioned in the code but running the code is deleting all the sheets in the Excel. I even tried with Index but it is still deleting randomly.**

```
Sub Delete()
Dim NalSheet As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each NalSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If (NalSheet.Name <> "Dep 1" Or NalSheet.Name <> "Test" Or NalSheet.Name <> "Loop" Or NalSheet.Name <> "Offset_Positioning" Or NalSheet.Name <> "Range_Cell Value") Then

ActiveSheet.Delete

End If
Next NalSheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Change all your `Or`s to `And`s. If you've got a sheet named `Dep 1`, the first condition would return false, but the second and onward would return true, so `Or`ing them all together returns true.

Comment: Also use `Select Case`. Much cleaner than the above `IF`. One more thing... If the sheets are in the workbook from where you are running the code then change `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deleting the ActiveSheet, not the sheet referenced in your loop.  ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook, etc. are always pretty sketchy to use, since it can be tough to ascertain what really is the active object.  It's always better to explicitly assign them to an variable and work with that variable.  Your code is VERY close to that, as you have the worksheet that you want assigned to the NalSheet variable.  Just change

```
ActiveSheet.Delete
```

to

```
NalSheet.Delete
```

and change your "OR" in your if statement to "AND" and you should be good to go.